# Fixed div on top for mobile phone

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I have a function that sticks my .page-title on top.

I'd like to make it work only under a width of 590px but I seem to have troubles with the double condition.

When I add the Width condition it stops working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollVal > 60) && $(window).width()  < 590) {
        $('.page-title').css({'position':'fixed','top' :'0px'});         
    } else {
        $('.page-title').css({'position':'static','top':'60'});
        $('.nav').css({'display':'none'});

    }
  });
});
```

Many thanks

Comment: You should be doing things like this with CSS media queries instead of JavaScript. They are much more reliable.

Comment: Can you use a CSS media query for the scrollVal statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is wrong.

```
if (scrollVal > 60) && $(window).width()  < 590) {
```

It should be

```
if (scrollVal > 60 && $(window).width()  < 590) {
```

or

```
if ((scrollVal > 60) && ($(window).width()  < 590)) {
```